# How to repair damaged system files?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, crash, boot, system-file

Recently my computer completely froze while playing a game. After a minute or so I did a hard-reset. However, when the pc powered up again, I got a message saying "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key". Since I hadn't modified my boot-sequence I figured things weren't looking pretty. I suspected a HDD-crash, but didn't look into it much further. A couple of hours later I figured I'd try to boot from my Windows-DVD. However, when powering up the PC, the windows boot-sequence started before I was even able to insert the disc! Windows proceeded to power up successfully, and now everything's working fine again.

However, I figured there still had to be a problem somewhere. I looked at the windows logs, but only found 2 entries referring to an earlier "unexpected shutdown". I ran chkdsk and found no problems. Finally I ran sfc /SCANNOW. SFC identified some corrupt files but was not able to fix them. Here is the entry from the log file:

```
2014-08-16 00:38:55, Info                  CSI    000004ba [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" of prncacla.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-08-16 00:38:58, Info                  CSI    000004bc [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" of prncacla.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-08-16 00:38:58, Info                  CSI    000004bd [SR] This component was referenced by [l:186{93}]"Microsoft-Windows-Printer-Drivers-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_prncacla"
```

I tried troubleshooting in advanced startup options, using automatic startup repair, but windows wasn't able to fix the problem.

I tried booting from my disc, but my PC somehow refuses to do so. (I remember getting the option "press any key to boot from disc" when installing windows, but this doesn't seem to happen now.) And I'm unsure of how to get into my BIOS to change the boot order. (Mashing Esc, F10 and F12 didn't do the trick)

So my questions are these:

- Does anyone know what may have caused the crash, subsequent startup failure, and the following 'automagic fix'?
- What are the corrupt system files responsible for?
- How do I repair these system files?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16496/discussion-on-question-by-jsquared-how-to-repair-damaged-system-files).